# How to Query Groups, Users in Custom Execution Listener?

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti

I created a new custom execution listener and wanted to query the groups where the user is member of using the services

```
public class CustomExecutionListener implements ExecutionListener {

   private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomExecutionListener.class);

   public void notify(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {

      String userID = (String) execution.getVariable("initiator");
      logger.error("userID = " + userID);

      List<Group> groups = execution.getEngineServices().getIdentityService().createGroupQuery().groupMember(userID).list();
      logger.info("groups.size() = " + groups.size());

   }

}
```

I expect to have group.size() = 2, but the execution listner always display group.size() = 0

Comment: are you using activiti embedded in alfresco or standalone?

Comment: I'm using activiti embedded in alfresco process services